# How to rewrite this RGeo query using AR/Arel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, postgis, rgeo

I have the following scope I've gotten to work with raw SQL:

```
class DeliveryZone < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.contains(addressable)
    point = addressable.lonlat
    where(<<-SQL.squish)
    ST_Intersects("delivery_zones"."shape", ST_GeomFromText('#{point}'))
    SQL
  end
end
```

Where `delivery_zones.shape` is a `geography(Polygon,4326)` and `point` is a `geography(Point,4326)`, for PostgreSQL types.

In a rails console, they are a `#<RGeo::Geos::CAPIPolygonImpl>` and `#<RGeo::Geos::CAPIPointImpl>` respectively.

I want to write something more akin to

```
where(arel_table[:shape].st_intersects(point))
```

... but that gives me this error:

> RuntimeError: unsupported: RGeo::Geos::CAPIPointImpl

Would love some help getting raw SQL out of my model! Also, I'm a RGeo/PostGIS newbie, so please don't assume I know what I'm doing. :D

Answer (score 0):

Please also don't assume I know what exactly you're talking about, but I use the `squeel` gem to write rails-style queries with `rgeo` and `activerecord-postgis-adapter`. Daniel Azuma wrote some great blogs about this topic which got me started a couple of years ago. Here is the first one of the series: http://daniel-azuma.com/articles/georails/part-1

From what I understand, this might help a bit:

```
class DeliveryZone < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.contains(addressable)
    where{st_intersects(:shape, addressable)}
  end
end
```

Note this only works if you've installed the squeel gem. And if you want to be particular about it, maybe you should use this instead:

```
class DeliveryZone < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.contains(addressable)
    where{st_contains(:shape, addressable)}
  end
end
```

Glad somebody else is using rails for GIS stuff. Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without `arel` or `squeel`:

`where("delivery_zones.shape && ?", addressable.lonlat.to_geometry)`

In general, this should work:

`where("point_column && ?", rgeo_object.to_geometry)`

Here's an example with a model of `City` with a point column called `coordinates`, which is a `st_point`. I want to query all the cities in a bounding box defined by two corner points (SE & NW):

```
box = RGeo::Cartesian::BoundingBox.create_from_points(
        City.first.coordinates, City.last.coordinates)

City.where("coordinates && ?", box.to_geometry)
```

What's going on?

```
> box.to_geometry.to_s
=> "POLYGON ((-90.0674 29.9627, -79.09529 29.9627, -79.09529 36.18375, -90.0674 36.18375, -90.0674 29.9627))"

> City.where("coordinates && ?", box.to_geometry).to_sql
=> "SELECT \"cities\".* FROM \"cities\" WHERE (coordinates && '0020000003000010e60000000100000005c05684504816f007403df67381d7dbf5c053c6193b3a68b2403df67381d7dbf5c053c6193b3a68b2404217851eb851ecc05684504816f007404217851eb851ecc05684504816f007403df67381d7dbf5')"
```

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, it seems like this will return all points within the polygon, right? Not just the ones that intersect the linestring that create's it's perimeter? I've been searching for this exact same thing for a week!

Comment: Yes, it will return all records with points (the `coordinates` column, in this case) inside the bounding box.